# Does existence of derivatives imply continuity? In regard to usage of Bernstein theorem for approximation using polynomials.

Tags: functions, numerical-methods

I have a function $f$ defined on interval $[a,b]$ and I know that all of it's derivatives exist and $|f^{(k)}(x)|>0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Does this imply that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and if so, why?

I need to prove that $E(f)= \inf \max\limits_{a \leq x \leq b} w_n \in \prod_n |f-w_n|$ is a decreasing function with regards to degree of the polynomial, and I want to use Bernstein polynomials and the proof with it for it, but Bernstein assumes that $f$ is continuous, and I have different assumptions about $f$, and I want to know if they are connected in any way.

Comment: The answer is yes; it's a standard result of introductory calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proof:  if $f(x)$ is not continuous at $c$, then $\lim_{h\to 0}f(c+h)\neq f(c)$.  Therefore $\lim_{h\to 0} f(c+h)-f(c)\neq 0$, and consequently $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$ is undefined.  Therefore, $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $c$.